# JqGrid highlight row

Tags: jqgrid, highlight

The JqGrid script can show a list of record loaded with ajax procedure.

Example:

```
<table id="tab_Categorize"></table>
<script>
jQuery('#tab_Categorize').jqGrid({caption: 'Title',url: 'CategorizeAjax.php?a=123',...});
</script>
```

Can i view in the list the row (id 123) highlighted?
Thank's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the row which you need highlight has the id `123` you can just use [setSelection](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) method for selecting:

```js
jQuery('#tab_Categorize').jqGrid('setSelection', '123');
```

If you download the grid from the server you should place the code inside of `loqdComplete` callback, because the data can be selected only after there are loaded.